# How to load comma separated numbers from flat file into sybase table using LOAD DATA statement?

Tags: sybase, sap-iq

My sybase table has column defined as numeric (col name: Balance). But the file that I'm loading has columns separated by "|" and the column has comma separated in the flat file in UNIX.

How to load this data which has comma in file (separated as lakhs, thousands, hundred: 99,999,999) but the column is numeric?

In oracle we had a function "replace" but functions are not allowed in sybase while loading.

Comment: You may have to either strip the commas from the source file or import the numbers as text first into the db and convert them to a proper numeric format afterwards.

Comment: `%s/,//g`  <--- sed to remove comma.  You can run that in vi, or add it to a script to fix your data formatting.  Or as shadow suggested, import into a temp table first, then convert the data to the proper format and move to production tables.